# Laravel using an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my blade I use an ajax call to call a route.  In my controller I am returning a different view.  However, the view does not change.  I am wondering if I need to change the view differently because I am using an ajax call that needs a return of success or not.

Here is my ajax code in my blade:

```
 $('#btnAnalyze').click(function(){
               var text = $('#cv').val();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/widget/measurableresults",
                    data: {
                        text: text,
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log("Success");
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Here is my route

```
Route::post('/widget/measurableresults', 'WidgetController@measurableresults');
```

Here the method in my controller:

```
 public function measurableresults()
    {
        $text = Input::get('text');
        Log::debug( $text );
        return view('results.measurableresults');
    }
```

The Log::debug prints out the value of $text and the ajax call returns success.  However, the view does not change to results.measurableresults.  What am I missing?

Comment: Use `window.location.href` then pass the url of the view to the response of ajax.

Comment: @aldrin27, can you give me an example?

Comment: You can refer to this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/redirect-after-ajax-post-request

Comment: As Tosin John pointed out, you are returning html but you are not doing anything with it. I think you are missing the theory behind AJAX. You will need to update DOM in the ajax success function.

Answer (score -1):

Try and remove the line `Log::debug( $text );`, it's probably blocking the `return` statement to execute

## update

You seem not to understand how things work in ajax and php communication, the success code you're receiving doesn't mean ajax returned the expected value, if you log the ajax response, you'll get the html text in the view you're returning, it's not that ajax will magically change the view for you.

Please make more research in regards to this.

Comment: I already tried removing the Log::debug().  I think dd() would stop the return statement for executing, the Log::debug() does not